# UICollectionView insetForSectionAtIndex not being called

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a class with the following declaration and constructor:

```
class GameView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    var collectionView: UICollectionView?
    var flowLayout =  UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    init (frame : CGRect, navigationController:UINavigationController, parentViewController: ScrambleViewController)
{
    super.init(frame : frame)
    cvFrame = CGRect(x: cvLeftBorder, y: cvY, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width) -  (2 * cvLeftBorder), height: cvHeight)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: cvFrame!, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout);
    collectionView!.dataSource = self
    collectionView!.delegate = self;
    .....
}
```

This is a game where there is a different number of cells each round.   I want to center the cells, so I inserted:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

 // calculate the insets and return a UIEdgeInsets
}
```

For some reason, the function is never called.   Otherwise, the program is working fine.   Or is there a better way to center the cells in each round?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you set the delegate and datasource of your collectionView like yourCollectionView.delegate = self/ yourCollectionView.datasource = self as I can clearly see that you have defined protocols of UICollectionView..???

Comment: Thanks @unexpectedNil   I have added more relevant code in my post.    In the code, I passed the UICollectionViewFlowLayout in the UICollectionView constructor.    I thought that was how to ensure the layout methods would be called.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 13):

This will work:

```
@objc(collectionView:layout:insetForSectionAtIndex:)  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)
}
```

Comment: This routine was not getting called after I converted to Swift 4.  The above @objc worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Answer (score 0):

The signature has changed in Swift 3:

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
optional public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

Answer (score 0):

sobremesa answer is correct, so to implement this method you have to use something like this:

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return yourInsets
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Eyzuky's answer would work. What you need to understand is that `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` is the child of `UICollectionViewDelegate` so I don't exactly know what would happen now that you are conforming to both of them.

The reason @Eyzuky's answer would work is that Objective-C doesn't have a strict conforming protocol like Swift but instead, if you have the function implemented in your conforming class, Objective-C will look to see if the delegate object is responding to that selector and as the delegate object is a weak reference to your class and your class currently has that function implemented, it does.

It's a basic mistake that people new to Objective-C usually think that they must have the `<UICollectionViewDelegate>` with their interface declaration for it to all work, but it doesn't really make a difference.

However, when doing that in swift, the respondToSelector method isn't being called anymore, therefore you can tell your collectionView delegate that it's ok and you can use my function by adding an @objc sign and the exact address of the protocol method.

Also, conforming to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as well as `UICollectionViewDelegate` might cause issues considering now there might be two different objects in place. I wasn't able to de-reference the same situation in my own code, but that might be what's causing your issue. I would suggest that you remove the `UICollectionViewDelegate` from your class implementation while having your collectionView delegate object to self. so the references don't get mixed up.

So your class would look something like this: 
`class GameView: UIView,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

and in your `collectionView` implementation you will have:

`collectionView!.dataSource = self
collectionView!.delegate = self`